# How to use UIView's contentStretch

Tags: iphone, uikit

I want to use an image of size 27x27 with the center 1 pixel stretchable as the backgroundImage of an UIButton. Here is my code:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 27.f, 27.f);
button.contentStretch = CGRectMake(13.f/27.f, 13.f/27.f, 1.f/27.f, 1.f/27.f);
[button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"long title", @"long title") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button sizeToFit];
CGRect buttonFrame = button.frame;
buttonFrame.size.width += 18.f * 2;
button.frame = buttonFrame;
```

But the result is no different from that without setting contentStretch at all.

So how to correctly use contentStretch to achieve what I want?

*Please don't tell me again and again that I can achieve the same effect with `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:`. I know that and it's apparently not what I'm asking for. I just want to know how to properly use `contentStretch`. Thanks.*

Answer (score 1):

One issue I see is that you're dividing using integer division.  1 / 27 is equal to 0.  1.0 / 27.0 is equal to 0.037...

If all you want is a stretchable background on your button, check out stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight: on UIImage.  Create the stretchable image that way, then set it to the background of your button.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the integer division problem. But it still does not work with float numbers. I know stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight: works. I just want to learn how to use contentStretch.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the special behaviour with UIButtons (I'd also suggest to use stretchableImages there as it is a compound view). However, if you want to use contentStretch you could do so on an UIView given your data this was:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
view.layer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_image"] CGImage];
view.contentStretch = CGRectMake(13./27., 13./27., 1./27., 1./27.);
```

This should be enough to have a UIView with a stretchable background.

Comment: Thank you. But do you know whether it is the intended use(or only possible use) of contentStretch? Apple's doc is so vague that hardly tells anything about how to use it.

Comment: The short answer is no I don't. I was only able to use it this way though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:]`.

I put this in the `init` method of a subclass of `UIView`:

```
// Add errorBackground & errorLabel.
rect.size.height = 26.0f;
errorBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
errorBackground.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ErrorBubble.png"]
                         stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:13 topCapHeight:0];
UILabel *errorLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
                       CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
errorLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
errorLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
errorLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
errorLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
errorLabel.text = @"1 Failed Passcode Attempt";
errorLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
errorLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
errorLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, -1.0f);
[errorBackground addSubview:errorLabel];
[errorLabel release];
[self addSubview:errorBackground];
```

ErrorBubble.png: 
[image: ErrorBubble.png]

ErrorBubble@2x.png: 
[image: ErrorBubble@2x.png]

Answer (score 1):

Unsatisfying but simple answer:

**You can't, until Apple fixes this.** IMO it's a long outstanding and very annoying bug.

The UIButton implementation consists of a couple of subviews, and the (internal) background view does not seem to reflect the settings done on the UIButton view.